# Returning an object's attributes in firebase returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The user exists but when trying to access its name, it returns null.

```
     Query userQuery = fireDB.orderByChild("email").limitToFirst(1);
    userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

            //playerList.clear();


                //dataSnapshot.getChildren().forEach(User.class);
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

               // Log.d("hi", user.getName());
                users.add(user);
                getUser(user,user.getName());
                Log.d("all users", users.toString());
```

Comment: Please add you database structure and respond with @PradyumanDixit

Comment: Please add you database schema as also PradyumanDixit asked you and please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

be sure you to type "email" correctly. it is case sensitive

Comment: Thanks but thats not the issue